# Miglayout aligning components to top of cell

Tags: miglayout

I have a group of buttons that will just stay in the middle of the panel. I am trying to place them at the top of the panel in a flowy layout constraint. Any help in achieving this is greatly appreciated. I have tried dock and align but didn't do anything.

```
private class ProductPanel extends JPanel {

    private JLabel lblProd;
    private JButton butAdd;
    private JButton butRemove;
    private JButton butEdit;
    private Product_Table_Model ptm;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JTable table;

    ProductPanel() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("debug"));

        ptm = new Product_Table_Model(
                (ArrayList<Product>) client
                        .receiveObject("Get_Product_Data"));

        initComponents();

    }

    public void initComponents() {

        lblProd = new JLabel ("Product List: ");

        buttonPanel = new JPanel (new MigLayout());
        butAdd = new JButton ("Add");
        butRemove = new JButton ("Remove");
        butEdit = new JButton ("Edit");
        buttonPanel.add(butAdd, "cell 0 0");
        buttonPanel.add(butRemove, "cell 0 1");
        buttonPanel.add(butEdit, "cell 0 2");

        butAdd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 50));

        add(lblProd, "wrap");

        table = new JTable(ptm);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

        add(scroll);
        add(buttonPanel);


    }

}
```

Comment: You need to provide a full example. There has to be another problem; the buttons in a flowy mode are aligned to the top by default.

Comment: updated with code, tried doing an image but I don't have 10 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons are aligned to the top, as expected. It is the panel itself that
was not aligned within its cell. So the following will fix the issue:

`add(buttonPanel, "top");`

You should not be setting the preffered size with a `setPrefferedSize()` method.
Instead, use size groups.

`MigLayout` is very powerful layout manager, you don't need to create two 
panels with two layout managers. It is possible to create your layout much easier. 
The following example is one such solution:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class ProductPanel2 extends JPanel {

    private JLabel lblProd;
    private JButton butAdd;
    private JButton butRemove;
    private JButton butEdit;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JTable table;

    public ProductPanel2() {

        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout());

        lblProd = new JLabel("Product List: ");

        butAdd = new JButton("Add");
        butRemove = new JButton("Remove");
        butEdit = new JButton("Edit");

        table = new JTable();
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(table);        

        add(lblProd, "wrap");
        add(scroll);
        add(butAdd, "split 3, flowy, top, sgx");
        add(butRemove, "sgx");
        add(butEdit, "sgx");        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                ProductPanel2 pane = new ProductPanel2();
                frame.setContentPane(pane);
                frame.setSize(350, 250);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });        

    }
}
```

The cell next to the table is split into three subcells. Three buttons are
inserted into these subcells. A vertical flow mode is set with the `flowy`
constraint. The `top` constraint aligns the buttons to the top. Finally, the
`sgx` constraint makes the button the same size.

[image: Snapshot of the example]

Comment: Have a look at the MigLayout cheat sheet. There you have all the constraints explained. It says that "it gives the component a size group name. All components that share a size group name will get the same BoundSize (min/preferred/max)." The syntax is one of: sg [name], sgx [name], sgy [name]. The buttons have the same height by default, so the sgx is sufficient in our case. There is only one size group in the example, so we did not have to give it a name.